# how to get all 'username' from my model 'MyUser' on google-app-engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, model

my model is :

```
class MyUser(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty()
    password = db.StringProperty(default=UNUSABLE_PASSWORD)    
    email = db.StringProperty()
    nickname = db.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

and my  method which want to get all username is :

```
s=[]
a=MyUser.all()
for i in a:
    s.append(i.username)
```

and i want to know : has any other way to show all 'username' .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many other ways to show all usernames. One is [templates](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html):

```
users = MyUser.all()
template.render('userlist.html', {'users': users})

<ul>
  <% for user in users %>
    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
  <% endfor %>
</ul>
```